# Can you find a formula for the supremum of an infinite collection of nonempty sets each of which is bounded above?

Tags: real-analysis

I believe the supremum of a collection of finite sets which are all nonempty and bounded above is simply the maximum of the set containing the supremums of each set, but can you find the supremum of a collection of infinite sets which have the same properties?

Part of me wants to say yes because it's still just the largest of the supremums, but part of me wants to say no because there's an infinite collection of supremums. Can you please help me?

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: Be careful: the sets $(-\infty,n)$ are bounded above, but their suprema aren't. Also: what do you mean by "find a formula"?

Comment: If the collection of suprema is infinite, there may not be a maximum. What about the supremum of the suprema?

Comment: So maybe the supremum of a finite collection would be max{sup(A1), sup(A2),...,sup(An)}, whereas the supremum of an infinite collection would be sup{sup(A1), sup(A2),...,sup(An),....}? Would that be correct?

Comment: There need not be  a maximum, so it's the supremum: $$\sup \bigcup_{\alpha\in A} S_\alpha = \sup \{ \sup S_\alpha : \alpha \in A\}.$$